# Full width background image in footer

Tags: css, wordpress, footer

I am working with 960gs (in my local environment) and I insert this CSS code into my `footer` div:

```
## style.css

#footer{
    background:url("images/footer.png")  repeat-x scroll top transparent; 
    height: 130px; 
    width:100%; 
    overflow:hidden;
}

## footer.php

<div id="footer">   
    <div id="nav" class="container_12">  </div>
    <div id="endfooter" class="container_12">
        <div id="copyright" class="grid_3 alpha"> </div>  
        <div id="design" class="grid_3 omega">  </div>  
    </div> <!-- endfooter -->
</div> <!-- end footer -->
```

The problem is that the page does not show the `footer` div at full width with the background covering the entire div. It just shows the image at 960px. What I am doing wrong?

Comment: How big is the image's container?

Comment: The dimensions are : 320px x 192px.

Comment: Then why are you trying to use a 960px image?

Comment: If i try to create an image with 960x120, with in the above code Should i have the result than i want? I want a full width footer, no an 960px footer.

Comment: I forgot.The strange thing is that this only occurs when I work Locally, when i run the project with index.html . The footer have full width.

Comment: Any answers of my query?

Answer (score 0):

It took me awhile before I realized what you are trying to do. You are trying to get a background image to scale, correct? You can't do that, at least in CSS2. Background images do not scale. You can tile them (repeat) but you can't scale them. If you want the image to scale you have to use an `<img>` tag.

If you are willing to depend on CSS3 standards you can use [`background-size`](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_background-size.asp)

```
#footer{
    background:url("images/footer.png")  repeat-x scroll top transparent; 
    background-size:100% 130px;
    height: 130px; 
    width:100%; 
    overflow:hidden;
}
```

I can't vouch for `background-size` but w3schools does claim good browser support.

Comment: Thanks for the help. But,why the initial part (at my first post) of code works at index.html and don't work locally? What is the different? i may have done something wrong at html (footer.php). I can not give any explanation

Comment: I replaced background-image to background-color and the result is the same. Color can't grasp the 100% of footer.

Comment: The first mistake of css code is the height of image. The original image height is 192px and not 132px; So the footer is now in full width, but isn't at the bottom of my footer.                                                                `#footer{background:url("images/footer.png")  repeat-x scroll center top transparent; width:100%;
height:192px;
position:absolute;                                     overflow:hidden;
bottom:0;
left:0;                                                       right:0;`

Comment: @MikeD position:absolute is the problem, i also face same problem

Answer (score 0):

I think that the footer is inside some container and the max-width of that container is limited to **960px**. So you can detect that container and increase its width. Or just you can give 100vw(viewport width) to the footer width:

```
#footer{
    background: url("images/footer.png")  repeat-x scroll top transparent; 
    height: 130px; 
    width: 100vw;     /* new */
    overflow: hidden;
}
```